# Can we enhance the fevd plot in R-studio?

Tags: r, var

I am plotting fevd for 14 variables after applying VAR and SVAR in R-Studio, but the output comes very overlapped, the detail of colors specified to each variable is not printed complete and the half of it that is printed comes overlapping the plot. I have tried changing the par("mar") but it doesn't help. Is there any way to tackle this?
here is a sample data (used dput)

```
   structure(c(-15.128286545, 9.54362378, -3.183102118, 2.455920412, 2.291578693, -2.375566455, -1.006170511, -0.3, 0.2, 0.07, -1.48, 1.66, 0.23, 2.69, 0.139816501, -0.067264912, 0.00820542499999988, 0.601791352, -0.534672832, 0.448348103, 0.201531496, 1.912707215, -2.298881719, 2.250845193, -100.270023362, 168.06388869, -29.13957144, -5.96895973, -65.094658064, 69.084085184, 77.852479576, -115.75847262, 1.07846378, 124.53936952, -136.67294405, 0.763694729, -3.181436503, 0.357452785, 1.419643891, -1.352477057, -0.352129671, -0.518658596,-40.982268397, 15.10208529, 8.81612737, 14.742141917, 0.331767914, -3.388439373, -1.705233303, 9.716651558, 17.163282893, -26.403831865, 5.522207566, -6.267360551, 8.793307298, 0.68190014, 6.571072841, 10.734436876, -15.768737701, 3.732193641, -3.013388691, 2.257042669, -3.092580854, -7.590788096, -0.377256109, -1.954321683, -0.655236714, 8.787007941, -11.048392421, -11.771665078, -9.286360071, 0.672766377, 4.540993395, -22.771472581, 33.33956332, -21.892993669, 3.082682577, -18.404892011, 6.039591015, -8.744388675, 4.5514676, 3.81637218,-8.616022054, 10.73600499, -27.792088246, 27.763201157, -20.582295417, 36.58994891, -33.462654905, 8.941944848, 4.666353971, -0.492222954, 0.443107902, -0.444468843, 0.378535534, 0.363633632, -0.396522691, 0.164774515), dim = c(7L, 14L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("QIM", "ML", "WPI", "BOT", "FDI", "TX", "FBT", "CP", "PHA", "NM", "AUT", "ISP", "FER", "ER")))

 #This is the command for fevd plot after applying VAR 
  vd <- fevd(estim, n.ahead=36)
    par("mar")
    par(mar=c(1.2,5,1.5,4.7))
    plot(vd)
```

[image: this is the plot that I am receiving.]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten sure, here it is

Comment: Hi @Adeel Ahmed, could you please share the output in your question above?

Comment: Sorry @Adeel Ahmed, but I can't reproduce your problem. I get the following error : `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ`.

Comment: AdeelAhmed, it's almost always preferred to put sample data in the question itself: comments can easily be skipped by readers, mis-copied due to the interface, or even hidden by the interface when there are many other comments. Please [edit] your question and add the `structure(...)` to a code block with the question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AdeelAhmed, are you sure that this is your complete code? Maybe we need the `VAR` function to reproduce your problem right?

Comment: @Quinten This is not the complete code I have shared some of the data that is reproducible, and yes VAR function has to be applied first

Comment: Could you please share that part too? So we can reproduce your problem exactly the same!